# Operator completly continuous

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

> For $\lambda>0$, let $v(t)=\lambda \phi(t)$. Consider the BVP
>   consisting of the equation $$u'''=\lambda[f(t,[u-v]^*+\gamma)+M(t)] ,t\in (0,1)$$
>
> and (BC):$u(0)=u'(p)=\int_q^1 w(s)u''(s)=0 , (\frac12<p<q<1)$
>
> - $[u-v]^* = u-v ~~\text{if}~~ u-v\geq 0 ~~\text{or}~~ [u-v]^*=0 ~~\text{if}~~ u-v<0 $
> - $G(t,s)$ is the Green function ,$ G(t,s)\leq a(t) b(s)$
> - $w(t)$ is nondecreasing and $w(t)>0$ on $(q,1]$
> - $e:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $e \in L(0,1)$
> - $\gamma(t)=\int_0^1 G(t,s) e(s) ds , \gamma(t)>0  \,\text{on} \,[0,1]$
> - $ M \in L(0,1)$ such that $M(t)>0$ on $(0,1)$ and $f(t,x+\gamma(t))\geq -M(t)$ fot $(t,x)\in (0,1)\times [0,\infty)$
> - There exist $r>0$ and $g\in L(0,1)$ such that $$f(t,x+\gamma(t))+M(t) \leq g(t)\,\text{for}(t,x)\in [0,1]\times[0,r]$$
> - $\phi(t)=\int_0^1 G(t,s) M(s) ds$
>
> **How to prove that  the operator  $T:K\rightarrow C[0,1]$ such that $K=\lbrace u\in C[0,1], u(t)\geq a(t)\,||u|| \text{on} [0,1] \rbrace
>  \subset C[0,1]$ $$Tu(t)=\lambda \int_0^1 G(t,s)[f(s,[u(s)-v(s)]^*+\gamma(s))+M(s) ds$$ is completely
>   continuous**

1)to prove that $T$ is continuous :

We take $(u_n)_n\in K$ which converge uniformally to $u$ in $K$ , and i must prove that $(Tu_n)$ converge uniformally to $(Tu)$

$|Tu_n(t)-Tu(t)|\leq\lambda \int_0^1 G(t,s)|f(s,[u_n(s)-v(s)]^*+\gamma(s))-f(s,[u(s)-v(s)]^*+\gamma(s))| ds$

$ \leq \lambda ||a|| ||b||\int_0^1|f(s,[u_n(s)-v(s)]^*+\gamma(s))-f(s,[u(s)-v(s)]^*+\gamma(s))| ds$

and then

$\max_{t\in [0,1]} |T u_n(t)-Tu(t)| \leq $

$\lambda ||a|| ||b|| \int_0^1|f(s,[u_n(s)-v(s)]^*+\gamma(s))-f(s,[u(s)-v(s)]^*+\gamma(s))| $

for all 
$s \in [0,1],|f(s,[u_n(s)-v(s)]^*+\gamma(s))-f(s,[u(s)-v(s)]^*+\gamma(s))|\rightarrow 0 $

and

$|f(s,[u_n(s)-v(s)]^*+\gamma(s))-f(s,[u(s)-v(s)]^*+\gamma(s))|\leq $

$ \displaystyle 2\max_{(s,x)\in [0,1]\times [0,||u||]} |f(s,x+\gamma(s))|$

fro Lebesgue we have $||T u_n-T u|| \rightarrow 0$,
 hence the continuity.

$x\in[0,||u||], ~~~\text{because}~~~ 0\leq [u(t)-v(t)]^*\leq u(t)\leq ||u||$

it's true ?

2) for the equicontinuity:

Let $t_1,t_2\in [0,1] $ and $u\in K$ then

$|Tu(t_1)-Tu(t_2)|\leq \lambda \int_0^1 |G(t_1,s)-G(t_2,s)|[f(s,[u(s)-v(s)]^*+\gamma(s))+ M(s)] ds $

$\leq \lambda \displaystyle \max_{[0,1]\times [0,||u||]}|f(s,x+\gamma(s))|+||M|| \int_0^1 |G(t_1,s)-G(t_2,s)| ds$

Let $\varepsilon >0$ , $G$ is the Green's function so it is uniformally contiuous , $\exists \delta>0$:

$\forall t_1,t_2 \in [0,1], \forall s \in [0,1], |t_1-t_2|<\delta \Rightarrow |G(t_1,s)-G(t_2,s)|\leq \varepsilon$

so $TK $ is equicontinuous .

it is true ?

Please ; help me

Thank you .

(Article: Positive solutions of third semiposone boundary value problems, proof of theorem 2.1 )